# Plot a histogram using Python with manual bins

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a histogram using the matplotlib.hist() function.

- Below code is not getting the correct histogram
- X axis is the years (age), X axis I want to have 0 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55
- Y axis is the probability

Someone can help me to get the correct histogram ?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

list_age = ['26','28','26','36','38','31','22','31','25','30','37','27','27','29','27','21','27','38','31','41','28','31','28','33','26','39','37','24','31','34','39','33','22', '30','24','29','28','34','27','28','26','26','25','40','24','37','24','28','26','29','26','31','23','31','36','32','25','31','25','33','36','27','28',
'25','27','39','36','30','31','34','23','31','32','31','33','32','39','35','35','22','34','25','35','35','41','20','21','35','32','30','22','21','23','33','25','30','24','39','24','27','22','33','30','27','30','23','29','30','22','31','29','31','24','29','25','24','26','29','31','24','32','21','25','29','30']

list_age.sort()

bins = 55

plt.hist(list_age, bins, facecolor='g')

plt.xlabel('Years')

plt.ylabel('Probability')

plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your *list_age* to a list of integers first (instead of a list of strings).
Then, simply use the options *density* (or *normed*) to display probability and *xticks* to change the ticks for the x-axis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

list_age = ['26','28','26','36','38','31','22','31','25','30','37','27','27','29','27','21','27','38','31','41','28','31','28','33','26','39','37','24','31','34','39','33','22', '30','24','29','28','34','27','28','26','26','25','40','24','37','24','28','26','29','26','31','23','31','36','32','25','31','25','33','36','27','28',
'25','27','39','36','30','31','34','23','31','32','31','33','32','39','35','35','22','34','25','35','35','41','20','21','35','32','30','22','21','23','33','25','30','24','39','24','27','22','33','30','27','30','23','29','30','22','31','29','31','24','29','25','24','26','29','31','24','32','21','25','29','30']
list_age = [ int(i) for i in list_age ]

bins = len(set(list_age))
plt.hist(list_age, bins = bins, density = True, facecolor = "g")    # Replace density by normed if older version of matplotlib
plt.xticks(range(0, 55, 5))
plt.xlabel('Years')
plt.ylabel('Probability')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

If you want to display the bars at specific bins, simply define bins at their coordinates:

```
plt.hist(list_age, bins = [ 0, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55 ], density = True, facecolor = "g")
```

Comment: I understand that the OP wants to have `bins = [0, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55]`.

Comment: It was unclear and the result appeared to be weird. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: It is not uncommon to have bins of unequal size.

Comment: One minor note: when setting `density=True`, the y-axis represents probability *density* (i.e. the derivative of probability), not absolute probability as suggested by the `ylabel`. This also implies that the y-axis can have a range that well exceeds 1 (which absolute probability cannot).